# Stuck on making the final API GET fetch with pre-flight cors failure for LinkedIn API

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I've been following the official docs at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&tabs=HTTPS1

Here we're instructed to:

1. Request an authorisation code (through member sign-in)
2. Swap this for an access token through a 'POST' request
3. Finally call the API endpoint for data using a 'GET' request

Using vanilla javascript and fetch to do this..

I'm stuck on the last one with the browser stating 'Access to fetch at 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

My GET request:
[image]

As you can see I have added the 'Authorisation' header etc. but no success. What is the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Exchanging the code for a token requires your client secret as a parameter - so that part definitively does not belong into client-side JS code to begin with. Not sure if you are supposed to consume the rest of it from the client side either.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your comments. It wasn't mentioned anywhere in the docs for these requests to be sent exclusively from backend / server side.. Although I suspect this can solve a lot of my issues. The diagram in the link only shows the 'client app' talking to the linkedIn server..
Further, I've seen php-based wordpress apps do this client-side but it's obscure and not easiy read. For dev purposes and mocking things up, I was hoping I could do this all client-side..